# How to disable the "What happened" popup in CodeRush?

Tags: coderush

This thing was great at first. For example, I comment a group of highlighted code by hitting the slash and the "What happened" dialog pops up and tells me what happened.

Now it is just freaking annoying. I only really needed to know what happened the first time. Is there any way to disable this thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "What happened?" dialog can be disabled from the options screen.

Use either the **[CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+O]** key combination or the **DevExpress\Options** menu to reach the options screen.

Then navigate the tree on the left to the **Core\Features**

The option you're looking for is the first checkbox on this screen.

If you **untick "Show Feature UI window"**, then this dialog will not show again.

Answer (score 2):

If you click the "OK" or "Disable" link in the "What happened?" hint - it won't appear for the specific feature anymore (it will remember your choice for this specific feature), but will appear for others only.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-ups only appear the first few times you do something to ensure you are clear what's been done, after that they stop appearing. I think you might be able to change that behaviour from the DevExpress menu.